# WPF TextBox format mask

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, format

I'am searching for solution to define a format mask for my textbox. I know for a masked textbox from Toolkit but it is not what I am looking for. I need currency format mask. Masked textbox from Toolkit has limitation for characters input. I don't want this.

I want to have a currency format like 1.000.000,00€ with no character limitations.

I also know for a StringFormat (with combination of local settings):

```
{..., StringFormat={}{0:C}}
```

but problem with this is that my TextBox is not bindable - no MVVM pattern.

So I would like to know how to define format mask on textbox which is not bindable?

----------> UPDATE

For now best solution is use of DecimalUpDown spinner from WPF Extended Tooklit.

If I could only hide those up and down buttons...

```
<wpfx:DecimalUpDown FormatString="C2" Margin="45,343,305,27" AllowSpin="False"  />
```

[image]

Regards,
Igor

Comment: I'm afraid, that's impossible, because `StringFormat` using together with `Binding`. The `StringFormat` works when you try to assign a value to TextBox via Binding.

Comment: I suspect that with StrinFormat wouldn't go. I hope for a different method.

Comment: You have to write an UserControl based on your textbox and make requierd properties bindable.